# Zend Framework 2 RESTful controller actions

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework2

After numerous attempts i can't get my rest functionality to work within my test application.

I wondered if anyone has experience with the RestfulController class in Zend FrameWork    2.0.0beta3.

I implemented the methods from the RestfulController abstract class, let the getList() method echo "Foo", did a curl request to get some output but all i keep getting is a blank screen.

I know there are options for zend framework 1.x but for my project i'm required to use 2.x.

If one of you could offer me some help that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I am working on same type of apps and so far it working pretty OK

Routing:

```
'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
'options' => array(
    'route' => '/[:controller[.:format][/:id]]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        'format' => '(xml|json|sphp|amf)',
        'id' => '[1-9][0-9]*',
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Rest\Controller\IndexController',
        'format' => 'json',
    ),
```

DI alias:

```
'alias' => array(
    'index' => 'Rest\Controller\IndexController',
    ...
)
```

in Controller, type of content that you return for rendering depend on your own strategy, it can be achieved in different ways.

In my case, it need to be able to response in various format such as: `php serialize`, `json`, `amf` and `xml`, I use `Zend\Serializer\Adapter` to serialize my content and directly return response instance, either you return it directly in controller action or centralized it by trapping RestfulController's dispatch event and return it via callback handler.

Quick Overview:

```
namespace Rest\Controller
{
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\RestfulController;

    class IndexController extends RestfulController
    {
        public function getList()
        {
            $content = array(
                1 => array(
                    'id' => 1,
                    'title' => 'Title #1',
                ),
                2 => array(
                    'id' => 2,
                    'title' => 'Title #2',
                ),
            );
            /**
            * You may centralized this process through controller's event callback handler
            */
            $format = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('format');
            $response = $this->getResponse();
            if($format=='json'){
                $contentType = 'application/json';
                $adapter = '\Zend\Serializer\Adapter\Json';
            }
            elseif($format=='sphp'){
                $contentType = 'text/plain';
                $adapter = '\Zend\Serializer\Adapter\PhpSerialize';
            }
            // continue for xml, amf etc.

            $response->headers()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type',$contentType);
            $adapter = new $adapter;
            $response->setContent($adapter->serialize($content));
            return $response;
            }

            // other actions continue ...
    }
}
```

also don't forget to register your module in application config

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell how you implemented it with the current information but Restful should work just fine with ZF2. I had it working in beta2.

- Make sure your controller extends RestfulController and your routes pickup the controller and id parameters correctly, ie. '/[:controller[/[:id]]]'. Use 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment' as route type.
- Using curl with the HTTP GET method and no id should call the getList() method. If an id is specified it will call get($id) instead.
- Instead of echoing, try returning an array.

You can also take a look at the [ZF2 Restful Module Skeleton](https://github.com/scaraveos/ZF2-Restful-Module-Skeleton) on GitHub for inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

Consider having a look at these ZF2 modules:

- https://github.com/farazdagi/zf2-rest
- https://github.com/epixa/zf2-rest
- https://github.com/scaraveos/ZF2-Restful-Module-Skeleton (disclaimer: I am the author of this)

Specifically the Module.php and config/module.config.php files might be of help.

Comment: Your module implementation is quite useful both as a module skeleton and as an example

Comment: I find your module is the best one out there, it's easy to understand and work with. I'm looking for a way to test the controller, can you provide me a good example of it [ I already created a github issue ]

Comment: regarding this https://github.com/scaraveos/ZF2-Restful-Module-Skeleton
what would we do, if we want to implement another get method but with different parameter ?